# How to add a new pip package to a deployed application with heroku

Tags: django, git, heroku, deployment

I have deployed a django rest api with heroku. And I have some updates regarding the code, For updating the source code is easy just updating the source code and commit changes with git. But I have trouble adding a new pip package. Is there a solution for this problem or do I need to re-deploy the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is to install the package in your virtual environment and using the `pip freeze > requirements.txt` command, update the requirements text file.

Once your done, commit the changes and push to heroku or github (depending on your setup)